# I have problems in storing two different items in one shared preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.uniqueid);

    simID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    simIMSI = getSubscriberId().toString();
    simID.setText(simIMSI.toString());
    SaveUniqueId(simIMSI.toString());


    uniqueID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
    identifier = UniqueIDTest().toString();
    uniqueID.setText(identifier.toString());
    SaveUniqueId(identifier.toString());

    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(UniqueIdActivity.this, LockAppActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(UniqueIdActivity.this, "Remember to keep the unique ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(intent);              
        }
    });
}

public void SaveUniqueId(String value){
    final String UNIQUE_ID = "UniqueIdentifier";

    SharedPreferences unique = getSharedPreferences(UNIQUE_ID, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = unique.edit();
    editor.putString("identifier", value);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getSubscriberId(){
    operator = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String IMSI = operator.getSubscriberId();
    return IMSI;
}

public UUID UniqueIDTest(){    
    UUID ID = UUID.randomUUID();   
    return ID; 
}
```

}

I am doing this activity and this activity will autogenerate a unique UUID as well as retrieve the sim card IMSI, how can I save these two items on a single shared preferences... please help me on my coding. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[see this link](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-shared-preferences.html)

in this demo ,i save name and pass instead of this you can save UUID and IMSI.

Comment: very helpful link... btw i hv another question... how can i retrieve the data from shared preferences of Activity A in Activity B?

Comment: same as retrieving data in A.

Comment: @Android_Rookie glad to help you ...but why not upvote now you have enough vote to upvote my answer...

Comment: Hi, I met another problem, I m creating a login layout for my apps... only correct password will be given access to the apps... but for the first time user, they can login a default password set by myself, after they set their own password, the new password will overwrite the stored default password, can i know how to do it?

Comment: you have to check first if wrong password then dont write in prefrence  if true then write ...

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences` use a Key:Value mapping that is one to one. You cannot store 2 values using the same key.

Your options are to use two separate keys or to combine the two values into a single value. One such way would be to combine the `simIMSI` and the `UniqueID` string via string concatenation:

```
String key = simIMSI + UniqueID
```